# SCP permission issues on gitlab-ci

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci, scp

i am trying to copy a file to my Server while deploying my application with the Gitlab-CI. At this point I can connect to the server with SSH but can't use scp.

My Pipeline looks like this:

```
 variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  DOCKER_TAG:
    value: "dev"
    description: "The Docker-Tag that will be used."

stages:    
  - deploy

deploy:
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o UserKnownHostsFile=./known_hosts $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "some docker-stuff"
    - scp -v -o UserKnownHostsFile=./known_hosts ./docker-compose.prod.yml -i $ID_RSA $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP:/home/$SERVER_USER
```

And I get following output of the SCP-Command:

```
debug1: Host 'xxxxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in ./known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
xxx@xxx: Permission denied (publickey,password).
scp: Connection closed
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 255
```

Anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just found out I have to use the command in different order:

Won't work:

```
scp -v -o UserKnownHostsFile=./known_hosts ./docker-compose.prod.yml -i $ID_RSA $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP:/home/$SERVER_USER
```

Works:

```
scp -v -i $ID_RSA -o UserKnownHostsFile=./known_hosts ./docker-compose.prod.yml $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP:/home/$SERVER_USER
```